# Pass data from one app to another app in angular 2

Tags: angular, iframe, angular2-services

I have embedded app2 inside app1 using an iframe. Now I want to pass data from app1 and show it in app2. How can I do it?

Comment: See [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: If only need to pass data in the initialization off app2 you can use simple html parameters that app1 passes via the url of app2.

Comment: can you show me an example code? @Vanderson

Comment: lets say you app2 entry url is 'app2.domain.com', you can pass parameters like this: 'app2.domain.com?var1=test&var2=true&var3=45&...', and than you can receive this parameters in app.component, injecting `ActivatedRoute` and getting this values. If this suits your need I can post a more complete solution in the aswers.

Comment: Thank you..I actually wanted to pass data to app2 and show it within iframe@Vanderson